# Similar attribute like drawer-toggle but does not toggle the drawer

Tags: polymer

Is there anything like `drawer-toggle` except that it doesn't toggle the menu?  I want to add a similar attribute to paper-icon-button to show/hide the icon button based on whether the drawer is shown or not.  I know I can get the boolean from `app-drawer-layout.narrow`, but my code is not exactly like the following and it's not easy to have an reference to `<app-drawer-layout>`.  The following is just an example of providing the context of what I meant by `drawer-toggle`.

```
<app-drawer-layout>
  <app-drawer>
    drawer-content
  </app-drawer>
  <app-header-layout>
    <app-header>
      <app-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="close" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div main-title>App name</div>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    main content

  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a boolean property to the `app-drawer-layout`'s `narrow` property and use this with an observer to show/hide the `paper-icon-button`. Example:

```
<dom-module id="test-app">
  <template>

    <style>

      .hide {
        display: none;
      }

    </style>

    <app-drawer-layout fullbleed narrow="{{visible}}">
      <app-drawer id="drawer">
        drawer content
      </app-drawer>
      <app-header-layout>
        <app-header>
          <app-toolbar>
            <paper-icon-button id="button" icon="menu" on-tap="_onTap"></paper-icon-button>
            <div class="title" main-title>App name</div>
          </app-toolbar>
        </app-header>
        <div>
          main content
        </div>
      </app-header-layout>
    </app-drawer-layout>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      is: 'test-app',

      properties: {

        visible: {
          type: Boolean,
          observer: '_visibleChanged'
        }

      },

      _onTap: function() {
        console.log(this.visible);
        this.$.drawer.toggle();
      },

      _visibleChanged: function(value) {
        this.toggleClass('hide', !value, this.$.button);
      }

    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Note that now you need to manually handle the drawer toggle (`_onTap` function).